# What is the reason of getting Secret ended with: too old resource version output in pod logs?

Tags: kubernetes

I've read a lot about this issue on google and here stackoverflow and noticed people saying these logs are expected nothing to worry about, but I often see the same logs in the pods and I am curious about how I can get rid of them. Please shed some light on that.

*Secret ended with: too old resource version*

```
W0528 08:24:35.191059       1 reflector.go:289] pkg/mod/k8s.io/client-go@v11.0.1-0.20190409021438-1a26190bd76a+incompatible/tools/cache/reflector.go:94: watch of *v1.Secret ended with: too old resource version: 136329240 (136330521)
W0528 08:39:29.197834       1 reflector.go:289] pkg/mod/k8s.io/client-go@v11.0.1-0.20190409021438-1a26190bd76a+incompatible/tools/cache/reflector.go:94: watch of *v1.Secret ended with: too old resource version: 136335511 (136336795)
W0528 08:55:35.204496       1 reflector.go:289] pkg/mod/k8s.io/client-go@v11.0.1-0.20190409021438-1a26190bd76a+incompatible/tools/cache/reflector.go:94: watch of *v1.Secret ended with: too old resource version: 136341573 (136343365)
W0528 09:09:04.216732       1 reflector.go:289] pkg/mod/k8s.io/client-go@v11.0.1-0.20190409021438-1a26190bd76a+incompatible/tools/cache/reflector.go:94: watch of *v1.Secret ended with: too old resource version: 136348121 (136349202)
W0528 09:24:00.224786       1 reflector.go:289] pkg/mod/k8s.io/client-go@v11.0.1-0.20190409021438-1a26190bd76a+incompatible/tools/cache/reflector.go:94: watch of *v1.Secret ended with: too old resource version: 136353600 (136355423)
W0528 09:41:36.231222       1 reflector.go:289] pkg/mod/k8s.io/client-go@v11.0.1-0.20190409021438-1a26190bd76a+incompatible/tools/cache/reflector.go:94: watch of *v1.Secret ended with: too old resource version: 136359660 (136362039)
W0528 10:01:07.237076       1 reflector.go:289] pkg/mod/k8s.io/client-go@v11.0.1-0.20190409021438-1a26190bd76a+incompatible/tools/cache/reflector.go:94: watch of *v1.Secret ended with: too old resource version: 136366767 (136369911)
W0528 10:13:40.244234       1 reflector.go:289] pkg/mod/k8s.io/client-go@v11.0.1-0.20190409021438-1a26190bd76a+incompatible/tools/cache/reflector.go:94: watch of *v1.Secret ended with: too old resource version: 136374636 (136374993)
W0528 10:29:30.251580       1 reflector.go:289] pkg/mod/k8s.io/client-go@v11.0.1-0.20190409021438-1a26190bd76a+incompatible/tools/cache/reflector.go:94: watch of *v1.Secret ended with: too old resource version: 136379692 (136381356)
W0528 10:48:00.278795       1 reflector.go:289] pkg/mod/k8s.io/client-go@v11.0.1-0.20190409021438-1a26190bd76a+incompatible/tools/cache/reflector.go:94: watch of *v1.Secret ended with: too old resource version: 136386083 (136388766)
W0528 11:03:41.285830       1 reflector.go:289] pkg/mod/k8s.io/client-go@v11.0.1-0.20190409021438-1a26190bd76a+incompatible/tools/cache/reflector.go:94: watch of *v1.Secret ended with: too old resource version: 136393524 (136395612)
W0528 11:20:01.292831       1 reflector.go:289] pkg/mod/k8s.io/client-go@v11.0.1-0.20190409021438-1a26190bd76a+incompatible/tools/cache/reflector.go:94: watch of *v1.Secret ended with: too old resource version: 136399874 (136401707)
```

Comment: What do you mean by `"get rid of them"`?

Comment: I want my logs to be clean and I could not figure why I have those logs in the pod. @Matt